# Big-O notation for algorithm

Tags: discrete-mathematics, algorithms, asymptotics

I'm working in an algorithm and I have achieved to know that its cost is $O \Big(\prod_{i = 1}^{N} i \cdot \log i \Big)$. I don't know how to simplify my cost even more.

Can anyone help me? Thank you so much

Comment: If you could provide more context everyone would have been able to help you better. You have to prove some properties of $O$. Check out https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Properties

Comment: @peter.petrov you seems true, i'm working on a greedy algorithm for TSP and I have bigger execution times than with brute force with lexicographic permutations. ^^'

Comment: You ought to start at $i=2$, or the product is $0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:
$$
O\left(\prod_{i = 2}^{i \leq N}i\log i\right) = O\left(N!\hspace{1mm}\log(2)\log(3)\dots\log(N)\right)
$$
The complexity shows that this algorithm is not by any means efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\prod_{i=2}^Nf(i)=\exp\sum_i\ln f(i)$ is approximately proportional to $\exp\int_c^N\ln f(x)dx$,$$\prod_{i=2}^Ni\ln i\in O\left(\exp\int(\ln N+\ln\ln N)dN\right)=O(\exp(N\ln\ln N-\operatorname{li}(N)+N\ln N-N))$$or thereabouts. The logarithm is asymptotic to $\tfrac12N^2\ln N$.

Comment: @RossMillikan I don't understand your objection. $\ln N!\in N\ln N-N+O(1)$; the logarithms' product provides an $\exp(N\ln\ln N-\operatorname{li}(N))$ factor.

Comment: I had thought that $N^2 \ln N$ was the final answer, not the log.